# How do I handle error logging for a system assembly without a circular reference?

Tags: c#, .net, circular-dependency, error-logging

I have a .NET assembly that wraps an XML configuration file. The config file contains a number of system settings including the path and file name formatting info for the error log file. Other assemblies reference this one through a singleton class:

```
public sealed class SettingsManager
{
    private static volatile SettingsManager manager;
    private static object syncRoot = new Object();

    //...

    private SettingsManager()
    {
        //load XML config file
    }

    public static SettingsManager Manager
    {
        get
        {
            if (manager == null)
            {
                lock (syncRoot)
                {
                    if (manager == null)
                        manager = new SettingsManager();
                }
            }
            return manager;
        }
    }

    //......
    //Methods getting and setting configuration data
    //......
}
```

I also have a `Logging` assembly that provides classes for error handling and usage tracking in the rest of the system. It references the `Settings` library to figure out where to save errors to:

```
SettingsManager.Manager.GetCurrentErrorFileName();
```

So the `Settings` assembly is a core dependency for the other assemblies in the project. But if I need to log errors in the `Settings` library I can't very well include the `Logging` assembly as a reference for `Settings` because I'll have a circular reference.

The problem I'm bumping into, is how do I handle errors that may be generated by the XML file routines in the `Settings` library? 
Do I hard-code a default file location for these errors to write to? 
What is best practice in this case?

I thought about the system event log, but these assemblies are going to be used in both a Windows service and a hosted MVC website. So I don't think the event log is an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two words... [dependency injection](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html#FormsOfDependencyInjection).

More likely than not, your `Logging` assembly has absolutely no business knowing about the `Settings` assembly. It should probably either:

1. Expect some environment variable to be set in the app domain telling it where to log, with a sensible default if not provided
2. Expect *something* to tell it where to log (perhaps by setting a property on the logger)

In either option, the entry-point to your app is a good place to do this. Maybe in your first few lines of code you'd do something like:

```
Logger.LogFilePath = Settings.Manager.GetCurrentErrorFileName();
```

Comment: Most of the applications I've worked on have been small in-house projects, or simple .NET or MVC websites. But the deeper I get into this project, the more I've been hitting on the concept of IoC and Dependency Injection. But it is still a new concept to me. If you know of any other good references for IoC and dependency injection, I'd love to know what they are. (I'm reading the di article you linked to now).

Comment: I like this one: [IoC container solves a problem you might not have but it's a nice problem to have](http://kozmic.net/2012/10/23/ioc-container-solves-a-problem-you-might-not-have-but-its-a-nice-problem-to-have/), but it's a big of a long-read. Here's [another one](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nblumhardt/archive/2008/12/27/container-managed-application-design-prelude-where-does-the-container-belong.aspx) that's shorter.

Comment: Or if you want a book on the topic, you could check out [_Dependency Injection in .NET_](http://manning.com/seemann/) by Mark Seemann.

Comment: I guess I have you to thank (or blame!). I've got some major refactoring underway. Fortunately it's still early on in the project, so I can afford to do it. Now that I understand the general concept of Dependency Injection, I realize I was mostly doing that already. But it's the idea of "decoupling" classes by using interfaces instead of concrete types that is new to me, and is what is inspiring the refactoring.

Comment: Hehe... if you start down the TDD (or unit testing in general) road you'll thank me again. It makes life much easier if you injection a class's dependencies as interfaces... then you can create mocks/stubs which makes testing behavior much easier!

Comment: This project also represents my first real foray into TDD. It's a bumpy road, but I'm getting there. And I can definitely see some of the short and long term benefits already.